# How can I switch between texture atlases based on the iOS version?

Tags: unity, textures, texture-atlas

How can I switch between atlases (with different resolutions) in Unity based on the runtime iOS version?

Comment: How are you building your Texture atlases? Texture2D.PackTextures()?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use Screen.currentResolution or Screen.width/Screen.height if you're trying to switch based on the resolution of the version.

If you want to get the exact version of iOS use SystemInfo.operatingSystem on Unity 4.3+ and iPhoneSettings.systemVersion on older versions